# MySQL select by payment interval like monthly, quaterly, halfyear, yearly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently working on a query that tells me whether the interval is in this month based on the payment interval (monthly, quarterly, halfyear, yearly) and the start date.

I have a table called "contract" and it contains the following fields:

- contract_start (DATE)
- contract_payment (VARCHAR)

Example:

```
contract_start = 2020-01-16
contract_payment = half_year
```

Is the start date taking into consideration the interval in this month? The command must be "smart" enough to also work with monthly, yearly and semi-annual.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can calculate the monthly, quaterly, halfyear, yearly *generally* in mysql, since your question doest give much of specifications.

```
  select 
        date_format('2020-01-16','%M') as Monthly,
        Quarter('2020-01-16') as Quarterly,   
        case when Quarter('2020-01-16') <=2 then 'half_year' else 'More then Half_Year' end as Yearly ,
        date_format('2020-01-16','%Y') as year
  from dual
```

Replace `'2020-01-16'` with contract_start and `Dual` with your `table name`